# Regex to get all target words after a pattern

Tags: r, regex

I need a regex to get all target words present in an alternation (in this case AMIDO or TALCO) that follows a word that begins with REVESTI, that may or not be followed by other words then the targeted ones, then performe the substitution through `gsub`:

```
st1 <- "LUVA TALCO AMIDO"
st2 <- "LUVA REVESTIDAS AMIDO TALCO LUBRIFIC"
st3 <- "LUVA REVESTIMENTO COM TALCO AMIDO "
list_strings <- list(st1, st2, st3)

lapply(list_strings, function(x) gsub("REVEST\\w+ .*?(AMIDO|TALCO)", "rev \\1;", x, perl = T))

[[1]]
[1] "LUVA TALCO AMIDO"               # CORRECT, because REVESTIXXX is not present    

[[2]]
[1] "LUVA rev AMIDO; TALCO LUBRIFIC" # WRONG, expected "LUVA rev AMIDO; rev TALCO;" 

[[3]]
[1] "LUVA rev TALCO; AMIDO"          # WRONG, expected "LUVA rev TALCO; rev AMIDO;"
```

In this [link](https://regex101.com/r/I2Pwu1/1) one may find this regex.

Would someone help me with this? Regards.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.1  tools_4.2.1     rstudioapi_0.14
```

Comment: @wictorstribizew, any thoughts on this matter?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
lapply(list_strings, function(x) 
  gsub("(REVEST\\w+)\\s+.*?\\b(AMIDO|TALCO)\\b\\s+\\b(TALCO|AMIDO)\\b\\s+.*", 
    "rev \\2; rev \\3", x))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] "LUVA TALCO AMIDO"

[[2]]
[1] "LUVA rev AMIDO; rev TALCO"

[[3]]
[1] "LUVA rev TALCO; rev AMIDO"
```

Comment: Dear @akrun, thank you. Actually, the real problem has dozens of targeted words, I can´t figure out how to scale your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex does the trick:

```
REVEST(?:\w* ?)+?((?:((AMIDO|TALCO)| )+ ?)+)
```

However, if there is a non-target word between two target words, then the second target word is not coptured (see forth line in the link below), to be worked on soon

https://regex101.com/r/I2Pwu1/3